# How to print/save pdf in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, jspdf

I have a screen where all the information related to user and their tasks will be displayed.. It's like a report. At the end I have a button for the user clicking on which will allow them to save a pdf version of the same information. The information will be different every time.. So the number of rows will be different. How can this be achieved? I tried using react-native-html-to-pdf but I could create pdf of only static html.. Couldn't figure out how to render dynamic html?
The ui will be slightly different for the pdf compared to the screen but the information will be same.

Comment: Typically pdf processing will be done and stored by the backend and you make the pdf available for download. I see that you haven't provided any feedback on answers to your previous questions. You may consider it, as developers may look at this before spending time on supporting your future answers.

Comment: In this case it's not done at the backend.. It needs to be done by the front end... Any solutions?

Comment: Sorry, I should've provided feedbacks.. Will do it.

Comment: Doesn't a simple `window.print()` work?

Comment: In react native? Umm.. I got to try that.. And even if it works.. I want to have different ui for the pdf.. So, I guess that is not what I need.. Thr content will be same and it will be a response from api and different everytime.

Comment: I have not much experience with react native. This tutorial seems to be helpful: https://aboutreact.com/react-native-print-html/

Comment: This is what I followed it worked fine.. But I want dynamic html.. And using this I could print only static html.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the post linked above, the following piece of code looks like an html string that you can modify as desired (sync or async regardless):

```
const printPDF = async () => {
    const results = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert({
      html: '<h1>Demo Text to converted to PDF</h1>',
      fileName: 'test',
      base64: true,
    });
    await RNPrint.print({filePath: results.filePath});
  };
```

It looks like that text can be dynamically changed, so you can replace it with any function:

```
const printPDF = async () => {
    const htmlString = await buildDynamicHtml();
    const results = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert({
      html: htmlString,
      fileName: 'test',
      base64: true,
    });
    await RNPrint.print({filePath: results.filePath});
  };
```